# Regular expression to match file names

Tags: regex

I'm dealing with a simple problem I guess.

I have a Cognos Report that leaves two files in a folder, after that an interface has to pick up one of the files depending on the filename to start running.

The report process asks the user to set a name to the report. For ex. if I choose the name `PaymentJournal06.09`, it creates these files:

```
PaymentJournal 06.09-en-us-xml_desc.xml
PaymentJournal 06.09-en-us.xml
```

I need a regular expression to pick up only the second file. I tried with `PaymentJournal*-en-us.xml` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close.  The `.` is a special character in regular expressions which matches any one character.  So where you had the `*` wildcard, you want a `.*` or a `.+` instead.  The first matches 0 or more of any character, and the second matches 1 or more, but both should work for this case.  Then, the `.` you used needs to be escaped, like `\.`, because you actually want to match a `.` there.  Putting it all together:

`PaymentJournal.*-en-us\.xml`

Answer (score 6):

with regular expressions the * is not a wildcard like you're used to, instead it is a quantifier meaning zero or more. So in your example:

```
PaymentJournal*-en-us.xml
```

`l*` means zero or more `l` characters, which would match:

```
PaymentJourna-en-us.xml
PaymentJournal-en-us.xml
PaymentJournall-en-us.xml
PaymentJournallll-en-us.xml
...
```

You need to use the . character which matches anything:

```
PaymentJournal.*-en-us.xml
```

Or you could be more specific:

```
PaymentJournal \d\d\.\d\d-en-us.xml
```

where `\d` matches a number and `\.` matches a period (.)

Comment: Indeed. You may also want to add beginning-of-string and end-of-string characters to the regex if whatever you're using to create it supports those easily.